# Download image using requests url problem

Tags: python, python-requests

I use this code to download image:

```
import shutil
import requests
url = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/25/11/55/cyberspace-2784907__340.jpg'

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

and it works. But when i use this type of link it dont work:

```
https://somesite.net/tor/poster.php/AOtJBawmVb0w7aHCjX5JmSo86CHVNKCFCz,KxohMSXIwMTIzNDU2Nzg5QUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU44N9qmOjPfy3FR58Dkq2XIpKhcjA1UPqrHlqXnX0kVs32sOTRn5f1QmKifHaeJ3Lwm80fo2bLATNETW1jZzTA=
```

if i put it in a web explorer, it shows, what is the best way to approach this?

I don't get an error when the image is downloaded, the file just says is not supported and i cannot get it to open in windows:

[https://i.imgur.com/I2CUZ2v.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4x29.png)

The link works:
[the link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjPxN.png)

Comment: How exactly does it not work? If you get an error please add the traceback to your question

Comment: because If you copy-paste the URL on google you will get a Not found error.

Comment: I don't get an error, the file just says is not supported and i cannot get it to open in windows.

Comment: FWIW I just tried that URL in Safari and I get HTTP 404 even if I URL encode the comma

Comment: the link is in a private site, i put there somesite.net to hide it, the link works

Comment: Please provide data to reproduce the issue (This link is dummy URL) OR put exact input/output/error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to add

```
response.raw.decode_content = True
```

before

```
shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```

If it does not work, could you please specify your problem and add correct "non-working" image URL?

Comment: it does not work, the link is in a private site, i altered my question to show that it works

Answer (score 0):

The image may not be png image. Check the first few bytes to see if it is png or jpeg or anything else.

png: `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`

jpeg: `FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01` or `FF D8 FF EE` or `FF D8 FF E1 ?? ?? 45 78 69 66 00 00`

bmp: `42 4D`

webp: `52 49 46 46 ?? ?? ?? ?? 57 45 42 50`

where question marks (`??`) are random bytes.

[Check this out for full list of file signatures and there offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: it is an proper image

Comment: no, i mean right click in the web explorer, then save image, then check the extension. You may be trying to open an image which may not be a png image but is saved as one.

Comment: It is this : https://i.imgur.com/qXSQ7kv.png @Timsib Adnap, but i can see it as an image

Comment: try and save it as "img.jpg". It should work.